# Remote payment without In-App Purchase service with iOS Client

Tags: iphone, ios, client, payment

i need more information about the remote payment through a client application iOS. I Know In-App Purchase and its functioning, but what i would like to understand is the possibility to manage all the server-side functions necessary to carry out the transaction banking, by notifying the client operations (payment ok, payment failed, etc), without passing through the Apple servers.
A trivial flow may be the following (assuming that the user has already been registered to a hypothetical web service and has associated with its own data bank account):

```
    - The user authentication to the server. 
    - The server verifies the correctness of the user's credentials and responds to the client. 
    - The server notification that there are payments in pending.
    - The user selects the payment to be made is the notification to the server.
    - The server performs the banking transaction (server-to-bankserver). 
    - The server shall notify the user that the payment was made or not.
```

The application, then essentially consists in the exchange of messages between the client and the server for the notifications of payments of some good or service (but the transaction is carried out to all the effects from the server), which are not digital content (as additional game  schemes or other digital content relating to the application itself.)
An approach of this kind could bring the application to be rejected by store? Does someone has already had similar experiences in this scenario to understand what may be the best solution for me?

(hope my question is not off-topic).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that Apple does not like it when you buy digital goods via any other means that via In-App purchase. Ans will reject you app for not doing so.

Comment: Thanks, i know this, but technically not the application that "buys the goods", but the server. The client receives only the notifications on the transactions effected by the server. I am wrong?

Comment: Great question. My context although is a little different. I'm not looking to sell digital content but a real-world service through the app (say for example, booking a cab). It's not a "product" per se but it's a definite mobile-centric feature of the service, that the client is paying for. Is it wrong to use a third-party payment system other than In App Purchase for this? I would love to find out

Comment: I too would love to know the answer to this.